# Custom (un)marshalling for xsd:union when genereting classes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, enums, xsd, jaxb

I'm working on an application that communicates by sending and receiving XML messages. These messages are defined in XSD schema. Now, we'd like to have the schema so in the future, we will be able to update it easily without completely breaking clients. I have solved most of the problems by adding `<anyAttribute>` elements to appropriate places. But I have huge problem with `<enumeration>` elements.

The idea is to use something like this:

```xml
<xsd:simpleType name="MyFruitEnumType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="APPLE"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="ORANGE"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="MyFruitType">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="MyFruitEnumType xs:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="Fruit" type="MyFruitType"/>
```

In practice, the `xs:string` would not be used, but when we update the schema like this:

```xml
<xsd:simpleType name="MyFruitEnumType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="APPLE"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="ORANGE"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="BANANA"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

We can create message with

```xml
<Fruit>BANANA</fruit>
```

and it will still pass validation using old schema (although client apps will have some default or error behaviour for this case).

But problem appears when we use JAXB's xjc to generate classes. `<xsd:union>` is genereted as Java's `String` property in `Fruit` class. Its understanble default behaviour, but I'd like to customize it, so the class `Fruit` would use `enum` `MyFruitEnumType`. I don't really care about the case, when String that doesn't match any `enumeration` arrives in XML. For example throwing some kind of validation exception is fine for me (or it could map unknown strings to some default value, etc).

I know about JAXB's `<typesafeEnumMember>` but I don't think I can use it here (or I don't know how). I also thought about `<javaType parseMethod=... printMethod=...>`, But I would need write the methods for tens of enums we already have, because I can't pass the enum itself to the parse and print methods to take advantage of enum's `valueOf()` method.

So to sum it up, the question is: **Can I customize how `xsd:union` is translated into Java class variable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, I declared binding in `xjb` file like this:

```xml
<bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='MyFruitType']">
    <javaType name="com.example.MyFruitEnumType"/>
</bindings>
```

and I created custom JAXB plugin, that customizes `XmlAdapter` generated by xjc to work with enum.